# Optimize MySQL Query (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I use MySQL & PHP and have the following database requests:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT nummer FROM abo WHERE usr = '{$usr}'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result1))
{
  $sendung=$row->sendung;
  $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT *
                            FROM filme 
                           WHERE sendung = '{$sendung}' 
                        ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 0,1;");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result2))
  {
    [...]
  }
}
```

For example there the second while is called 20 times -> there are 20 database request. But could I connect this request or optimize this requests?

One approach:

```
$arraysendung = array();

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT nummer FROM abo WHERE usr = '{$usr}'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result1))
{
  array_push($arraysendung,$row->sendung);
}
```

But how could I use `$arraysendung` in one request (is it possible)?

Comment: [Start here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query:

```
SELECT filme.*
FROM filme JOIN 
    (SELECT sendung, max(datum) as datum FROM filme GROUP BY sendung) as md 
    ON filme.sendung = md.sendung AND md.datum = filme.datum
WHERE filme.sendung IN (SELECT nummer FROM abo WHERE  usr = '{$usr}')
```

should produce similar results, including the "LIMIT 1 part", provided "sendung,datum" is unique.

See: [Subqueries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subquery#Subqueries), and JOIN

Comment: thanks! why 'SELECT filme.*' and not 'SELECT *'?

Comment: `SELECT *` would include the fields from md alias, which are duplicates of the ones in filme, `SELECT filme.*` only includes the relevant fields.

Comment: MySQL Error: "#1052 - Column 'sendung' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous" sendung is a varchar(255) in filme... what must I change?

Comment: edited the answer. `WHERE sendung IN` should be `WHERE filme.sendung IN`

Answer (score 2):

Use a [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

```
SELECT nummer, filme.*
FROM abo
JOIN filme ON filme.sendung = abo.nummer
ORDER BY datum desc
```

This isn't a 100% replacement, since the LIMIT stuff isn't in place, but should be enough to get you started.

For the most part, anytime you're running two+ queries, and the later queries are based on results from of earlier queries, you can almost always rewrite them into a single JOINed query.

Comment: Actually, adding the "limit part" is not trivial. Also, you have a error in the JOIN condition it should read `filme.sendung = abo.nummer`

Comment: Tpyo[sic] fixed. thanks.